# How to adjust screen resolution?

Tags: linux, debian, resolution, xorg.conf

I've installed Debian testing from `netist` image in a AMD Radeon system. I am using `Xorg` and awesome wm. The default screen resolution is 1024x768 while my screen supports 1366 x 768.

I've tried `xrandr` and `fglrx` but they failed.

A proprietary ATI drivers however solved this problem, but gives a slow scroll effect.

I've also used crunchbang Linux and it displays the corect resolution without a `xorg.conf` or ATI drivers.

Comment: It might help if you give versions of all the software you're using. Have you tried using amdCCCle with the proprietary drivers installed to tweak settings?

Answer (score 23):

I have never seen xrandr failing at setting up even the most exotic monitor resolutions, but I have seen it misused very often.
I'll post the exact sequence of commands for xrandr. If you have followed the same steps please ignore my answer.

1. Use `cvt` to calculate the parameters needed by xrandr:

   ```
   cvt 1366 768
   ```

   example output:

   ```
   # 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
   Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
   ```
2. build the xrandr command with the output of cvt:

   ```
   xrandr --newmode "1366x768" 85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -Hsync +Vsync
   ```

   please note Hsync and Vsync capitalized. I needed to do that to get things working on some systems
3. Add a newmode in xrandr:

   ```
   xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1366x768"
   ```

   Replace VGA1 as needed
4. Enable the new resolution:

   ```
   xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1366x768"
   ```

Comment: I extended my case here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307181/16920 about Asus Zenbook UX303UA.

Comment: -1, where is the GUI?