# On Debian : Must create and set as default resolution. How?

Tags: linux, debian, resolution, vga, default-settings

I'm running Debian Wheezy on a Mac Mini G4 PowerPC and i'm trying to set it up to output its correct monitor resolution on startup. I am using LXDE GUI.

The thing is, the LXDE resolution applet simply cannot recognize the monitor (most probably because it's a DVI output with a DVI to VGA adapter, going into a VGA monitor) therefore i do not have any options to set as default or anything via GUI :/

The resolution the monitor can output via VGA is 1360 x 900.

I followed these two tutorials :

[How to adjust the screen resolution in Debian?](https://superuser.com/questions/716795/how-to-adjust-the-screen-resolution-in-debian)

and

http://www.sudo-juice.com/change-lxde-screen-resolution-ubuntu-lubuntu/

Since none worked (well, couldn't set as default, but i could get the 1360x900 output to work but couldn't make it work on startup), I tried, inside the autostart file, creating the newmode, adding the newmode than output that mode. My autostart has these three lines :

```
@xrandr --newmode "1360x900" 100.25 1360 1440 1576 1792 900 903 913 934 -Hsync +Vsync

@xrandr --addmode DVI-0 "1360x900"

@xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode "1360x900"
```

In other words i tought that the autostart executes these commands in order therefore it would bring up the desired resolution.

Help please i am totally lost. (i'm a new user please teach me :'( )

Comment: What do you mean by "autostart file"?

Comment: Dear friend, first, thank you for the interest. Here is what i meant by autostart : the file located at /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart i hope this helps you helping me out!!